# How do I center a Group of list Elements along with putting them side by side?

Tags: html, list, alignment

Here is my code, I am making a Sign up page

```
<div class="form">
  <ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tabsignup"><a href="/signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li class="tablogin"><a href="/login.html">Log In</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In this code I want the list that is centered but also next to each other, Please help me with this!

Comment: please share your styles, have you tried using flexbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul{
display:flex;
list-style-type:none;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
border:solid 1px blue;
height:50vh;
}

li{
margin:0 4vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tabsignup"><a href="/signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li class="tablogin"><a href="/login.html">Log In</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Works perfectly! Appreciate the Help!

Comment: please accept answer if it works for you, thanks